# Is it possible to create concurrent index in PostgreSQL using Hibernate?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application which uses Hibernate for connecting to PostgreSQL with `auto-ddl` enabled. Now I want to use Hibernate to create an index on a table `CONCURRENTLY`.

I tried using the `@Index` annotation, but it just creates indexes normally.

```
@Table(name = "users", indexes = {
    @Index(columnList = "current_id", name = "current_id_index")
    })
```

Here is my "create index" query:

```
CREATE INDEX  concurrently IF NOT EXISTS current_id_index
 ON schema.users
 USING btree (current_id);
```

Is there a way to create the index `concurrently` using `@Index` annotations?